# Check all checkboxes only if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have a VBA code that checks/unchecks all checkboxes. However I want the code to check/uncheck only the checkboxes that don't a have 'False' written in them in column E5:E150.

Any help would be appreciated, here is my code :

```
Sub SelectAllSubSector()

    Dim cBoxSector As CheckBox

    For Each cBoxSector In Worksheets("Input attractivite").CheckBoxes
        If Not Intersect(cBoxSector.TopLeftCell, Range("C5:C150")) Is Nothing Then
            If cBoxSector.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 3").Name Then
                cBoxSector.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 3").Value
            End If
        End If
    Next cBoxSector

End Sub
```

Comment: `if cBoxSector.TopLeftCell.offset(0,2)<>"false"`  i've not tested this.  Or use `cBoxSector.TopLeftCell.row` to build another way

Comment: I am new to VBA. I tried the using the first solution and it does not seem to work on my end.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?  I  cant see your screen.

Comment: I modified the code by adding : ```if cBoxSector.TopLeftCell.offset(0,2)<>"false" before cBoxSector.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 3").Value``` . The worksheet contains a checkbox at C5 that checks/unchecks the other checkboxes in range C5:C150. When the value in column E5:E150 is 'False', I'd like the macro (C5) to always uncheck the checks that have a 'False' in their corresponding E row.